# Can I create factor groups based on repeating pattern in a time series in R?

Tags: r, group-by, grouping

I have time series data with a repeating pattern that I wish to label/group as separate factor levels each instance it occurs.  The example below uses a sequence of 1:100, but my real data is based on a time series: day-of-the-year. I've used a conditional test in my data to identify each instance that the pattern is present - this is simulated with a simple TRUE/FALSE column below (In my real data I'm looking for each instance where a trend line goes outside a particular threshold (standard-deviation)).

From the data below, is there a way to group each set of 'TRUE' values? Perhaps a way to identify the start/stop of each TRUE sequence (rows 26:50, and 76:100) and somehow create two separate group factor levels?

I've attached an image below to illustrate my end goal of trying to identify areas of a curve that exceed a particular boundary.

```
data = data.frame(order = seq(1,100),
              test = rep(c('False','True'), each = 25))
```

[image: If this helps - I'm trying to identify each instance the red line jumps outside the blue standard deviation]

Comment: How about `data %>% mutate(Group = data.table::rleid(test))`

Comment: @Mako212 I think this is just what I wanted for this question! This gives me a grouping variable created for each 'cluster' of TRUE or FALSE. I can filter out either one as needed later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(data, col = data.table::rleid(data[,2]))
```